# Allow space in Character name c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to allow a "space" 0x20 aka vk_space,in this code provided in the link..

It doesn't matter what I do to unblock the blocks in the code it still throws an error when trying to add spacing in the character name:

```
if ( (*chr) == ' ' || (*chr) == '\t' || (*chr) == '\n' || (*chr) == '\r'
    || (*chr) == '%' || (*chr) == '#' || (*chr) == '&' || (*chr) == '?'
    || (*chr) == '+' || (*chr) == '='
)
```

I tried commenting these out well atleast the very first one for the vk_space.

I actually got somewhat close adding space to this line of code throughout this code:

```
if ( !((*chr) >= 48 && (*chr) <=57)  //! 0 ~ 9
    && !((*chr) >= 65 && (*chr) <=90) // ! A ~ Z
    && !((*chr) >= 97 && (*chr) <=122) // ! a ~ z
)
```

If I could understand this above code for windows 1251 I believe I could get it to work.

The process to press ok and create the character is found here.

```
void CUICharacterCreateNew::PressOk()
```

Code is located here:

- http://lastchaos.org/UICharacterCreateNew.cpp
- http://lastchaos.org/UICharacterCreateNew.h

Comment: Perhaps use [`std::isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) to check for space? And please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you mean the character `'A'` then *say* so. Or better yet, use [`std::isalnum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum) if you want to check for an alpha-numeric character.

Comment: "it still throws an error when trying to add spacing in the character name" - what error? the code you shown does not try tro add anything.

Comment: CTString strMsg = _S( 146, "Do not enter spaces in the character name." );
http://prntscr.com/g5bron <--- THERE error live 
that's the translation for that

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Please tell us what _"space" 0x20 vk_space 57, kid space"_ is supposed to mean.

Comment: @MichaelWalz i am not sure how i could provide an example if you dont have the full client ~3gb the gameserver and client source code ~15gb..Without out that it's not going to be possible to give a small complete example :/ i wish it was

Comment: @PrestonBaes that's what the _Minimal_ part is about. You need to extract the problematic part, of course this implies some work for you.

Comment: VK_space is part of the WInUser.h inside the visual studios SDK 7.0a

VK meaning virtual key and kid is part of the games coding that links to the Virtual keys
the keynames i have created are labeled here
www.lastchaos.org/KeyNames.h

Comment: What does adding a space to a string have to do with a video game?  When we learn how to use `std::vector`, do we need to see the source to an entire app like Excel or AutoCad?  So what's the reason for the thousands of lines of code to try to explain a simple issue?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Because it is a video game im trying to allow a space in characters name when they create their character.. didn't realize it was that confusing.
MichaelWalz there's no way i can create something that needs to be inside a video game client, outside it, to recreate said error..

Comment: @PrestonBaes "_there's no way ..._" So, we cannot help you, if you are too lazy, to manufacture [mcve].

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius lazy isn't the word.. i'd have to rewrite 100,000 lines of code.. im looking for ways to allow space not rewrite the whole code

Comment: You write: _it still throws an error_. Which error ? Be more specific.

Comment: You probably just need to remove the `(*chr) == ' ' ||` part, so a space character won't be detected. But this may cause problems elsewhere, because other parts of the code _might_ assume that a player name doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: @PrestonBaes You wouldn't. Such a simple task as inserting a space in a string doesn't require 100.000 lines of code. And even if it does in your code - you would need to rewrite it entirely, anyway, so that it wouldn't need that.

Answer (score 0):

had to comment out all the char == ' ' ||

```
if(/* (*chr) == ' ' ||*/ (*chr) == '\t' || (*chr) == '\n' || (*chr) == '\r'
    || (*chr) == '%' || (*chr) == '#' || (*chr) == '&' || (*chr) == '?'
    || (*chr) == '+' || (*chr) == '='
)
```

and then i had to add 32 to the bottom of all these

```
if ( !((*chr) >= 48 && (*chr) <=57)  //! 0 ~ 9
    && !((*chr) >= 65 && (*chr) <=90) // ! A ~ Z
    && !((*chr) >= 97 && (*chr) <=122) // ! a ~ z
    && !((*chr) == 32 )
```

i was reading all these numbers as to windows 1251 encoding 20 = space.. well come to find out these are actually decimal and i need them to be hex. blah oh well :/